# $scope.form.$setSubmitted is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with angular, but when I try to call `$scope.myForm.$setSubmitted()` it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

I get this error:

> $scope.myForm.$setSubmitted is not a function

It should be possible, based on the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

> `$setSubmitted();`
>
> Sets the form to its submitted state.

I also seem to have some problem with `$touched` in the line:

```
ng-if="myForm.myValue.$error.min && (myForm.myValue.$touched || myForm.$submitted)"
```

So, two questions,

1. Why can't I call `$setSubmitted()`?
2. Why can I not get the `$touched` flag from the `input`?

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
  var vm = this;
  vm.submitTheForm = function(){
    $scope.myForm.$setSubmitted();
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
    <form name="myForm" ng-submit="ctrl.submitTheForm()" >
      <input type="submit" value="submit" text="foo">
      <input type="number" class="" name="myValue" max="10" ng-model="foo" max="10" min="0" number="{}" placeholder="enter a number" />
      <div ng-if="myForm.myValue.$error.min && (myForm.myValue.$touched || myForm.$submitted)">Must be a positive number. This should be seen if input is touched or the form is submitted.</div>
      <div ng-if="myForm.myValue.$error.max && (myForm.myValue.$touched || myForm.$submitted)">Cannot be larger than 10. This should be seen if input is touched or the form is submitted.</div> 
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <tt>myForm.myValue.$valid = {{myForm.myValue.$valid}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.myValue.$touched = {{myForm.myValue.$touched}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.myValue.$error.min = {{myForm.myValue.$error.min}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.myValue.$error = {{myForm.myValue.$error}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.$submitted = {{myForm.$submitted}}</tt><br/>
      <tt>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</tt><br/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's angular version problem https://jsfiddle.net/e2anqr3c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using AngularJS v1.2.23 which does not support `$setSubmitted()` [AngularJS v1.2.3](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.30/docs/api/ng/type/form.FormController), it's only supported after v1.3.0

Comment: So true. Thanks. Weird that the snippets only support the older versions...

Comment: No worries, glad can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.myForm.$setSubmitted` is not a function!
This solution may not be very specific to this question but generally we get this error when we try to assign `setSubmitted` to an object instead of a function.

`$scope.myForm.$setSubmitted = function(){}` will solve the problem.